# Grails: duck typing and many-to-many collection classes

Tags: grails, many-to-many, duck-typing

In my Grails app, a Person has a Fondness for Something - and that Something could be an Idea, a Decision, a Group, or another Person.

In Java I would impose a Something interface so that each of these classes could be passed in as a Something type.

In Groovy/Grails, I had it working where Something is a Groovy class and the Fondness class is a collection class that mapped Persons to Somethings.

I stumble when I try to leverage Duck Typing in this instance. How do I set up a collection class mapping Person to any of my group of classes, without imposing an interface?

Thanks for any advice! I am excited to hear how G/G developers would approach this.

-Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across this [Nabble thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Association-to-any-domain-class-td3081185.html) which may be similar to what you're after. It's an interesting solution, and seems kind of hacky, but would probably work alright.

Here's a code sample from the thread (courtesy of [Martin Dow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66722/martin-dow) - if he runs across this and posts this as an answer, I'll remove it from my answer and give him the upvote).

```
class SomeDomainClass { 
  Long associationId
  String associationClass
  def getAssociation() {
    // Handle proxied class names
    def i = associationClass.indexOf('_$$_javassist')
    if (i > -1) associationClass = associationClass[0..i-1]
    getClass().classLoader.loadClass(associationClass).get(associationId)
  }
  def setAssociation(association) {
    associationId = association.id
    associationClass = association.class.name
  }
}
```

Here are a couple options that do involve types that might give you some direction.

**Enums**

```
class Person {
    static hasMany = [fondnessess: Something]
}

enum Something {
    ONE_SOMETHING,
    ANOTHER_SOMETHING;
}
```

**Inheritance**

(I'm not the hugest fan of inheritance, but sometimes it's an okay solution.)

```
class Person {
    static hasMany = [somethings: Something]
}

class Something {
    // could be abstract, but look out for
    // http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6780
}

class OneSomething extends Something { ... }

class AnotherSomething extends Something { ... }
```

It kind of depends on how much logic each `Something` implementation needs to define. Both of these examples can be made to work, and there are probably other solutions out there, too.

Comment: I was wary of declaring a superclass for this group of very different kinds of classes but I see that a superclass like the Object class in java will work - I simply declared an empty superclass Something and had Idea and Person extend it. I then can have Person and Idea be superclasses to other domain classes if I need to. Duck Typing comes to bear in that I don't have to go as far as implementing an abstract Something class.  Thanks for helping me think about this.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is an abstract base class. Support for that is much improved in 1.4 - see http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2583 - and you can use it in 1.4M1 which will be released this week.